# How to set disable/readonly of <p:inputText> on change of <h:selectOneMenu>?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using `<p:dataTable>` within that I used html `<table>`. I want to disable/readonly PrimeFaces `<p:inputText>` on `<h:selectOneMenu>` change event.

I used JavaScript, but it is not working with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function change(val)
 {          
     //alert(val);
     if(val=="Check")
      {

         document.getElementById('bankName').readonly=false;
         document.getElementById('receiptNo').readonly=true;

      }
      if(val=="Cash")
      {

          forms.elements["mainForm:chkNo"].readonly=true;
          document.getElementById('chkNo').readonly=true;
          document.getElementById('bankName').readonly=true;
          document.getElementById('receiptNo').readonly=false;              

      }
}
</script>
```

JSF Code

```
<h:column>
                            <p:dataTable id="paymentHistoryDataTable" var="due" 
                                         >

                                <p:column>
                                    .......
```

```
                                    <table id="paymentProcess">
                                        <tr>                                                
                                            <td style="width: 80px;">
                                        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{adminActionController.tempBean.selectType}" id="type" onchange="change(this.value);">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Check" itemValue="Check"/>
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Cash" itemValue="Cash"/>
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr id="check">
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td style="width: 90px;" id="lblChk">
                                                <label> <h:outputText value="Check/DD Number:" /> </label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 90px;">
                                        <h:inputText id="chkNo" value="#{adminActionController.tempBean.checkNumber}"  immediate="true"
                                                     required="false" validatorMessage="insert Check/DD number">
                                        </h:inputText>
                                        </td>
```

................
I want to access id="chkNo" in js for disable it..

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive, you should always use "readOnly", using "readonly" is wrong.

Comment: i used that, still it is not disabled

Comment: Please provide complete code with HTML, also I don't think using "forms.elements" is correct.

Comment: Please don't use `[jsf-1.2]` tag if you don't have a question about JSF 1.2 at all. Please don't use `[ajax4jsf]` tag if you aren't using RichFaces' `<a4j:xxx>` components at all. Please don't use `[css]` tag if the question isn't about CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're making several conceptual mistakes here.

Your concrete problem is caused by that you're writing JavaScript code based on the JSF source code. This is not entirely right. JSF runs on webserver and produces HTML. JavaScript runs on webbrowser and sees HTML only, not JSF. Rightclick the page in webbrowser, choose *View Source* and look closely at it. There doesn't exist any HTML elements with ID `bankName` or `receiptNo`. Instead, it are `formId:tableId:0:bankName`, `formId:tableId:1:bankName`, `formId:tableId:2:bankName`, etc. In principle, you should have used exactly those HTML element IDs in JavaScript to select elements from the HTML DOM.

But this is clumsy.

Rather use JSF-provided tags/facilities to achieve the desired functional requirement. You can use JSF expression language in `readonly` such as `readonly="#{dropdown.value == 'Cash'}"`. You can use `<f:ajax>` to execute a JSF ajax request to update the model and the view.

The following kickoff example should give you a good starting point:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{adminActionController.tempBean.selectType}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Check"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Cash"/>
    <f:ajax render="chkNo bankName receiptNo" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:inputText id="chkNo" readonly="#{adminActionController.tempBean.selectType == 'Cash'}" />
<p:inputText id="bankName" readonly="#{adminActionController.tempBean.selectType == 'Cash'}" />
<p:inputText id="receiptNo" readonly="#{adminActionController.tempBean.selectType == 'Check'}" />
```

The `<f:ajax>` will update the components with (relative) client ID `chkNo`, `bankName` and `receiptNo` when the dropdown is changed. The update will force the `readonly` attribute to be re-evaluated.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the way how you used `<p:dataTable><table>` wherein you didn't bind the rows to `var="due"` is very strange, but that's subject for a possible future question/problem. The above code example assumes the right context.

Comment: thnx, and am trying assign selectOneMenu value to adminActionController.tempBean.selectType but it is not assigning to it. am taking it from request.getParameterMap();

Comment: This is most likely caused by your strange `<p:dataTable><table>` construct wherein the input values are not been bound to `var="due"` at all (and effectively becomes the value of the **last** record everytime).